# Pandas multiindex, drop rows where condition remains true?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multilevel dataframe

```
                          Buy     Sell
Date       Time                       
2018-01-03 11:36:00  24380.50      0.0
           11:37:00  24392.55      0.0
           11:38:00  24392.80      0.0
           11:39:00  24383.90      0.0
           11:48:00  24379.95      0.0
           11:49:00  24393.55      0.0
           11:50:00  24391.55      0.0
           11:51:00  24394.30      0.0
           11:52:00  24391.40      0.0
           11:53:00  24397.20      0.0
           11:54:00  24407.45      0.0
           11:55:00  24404.15      0.0
           11:56:00  24401.95      0.0
           11:57:00  24395.90      0.0
           12:29:00  24387.60      0.0
           12:31:00  24390.45      0.0
           12:33:00  24393.80      0.0
           12:34:00  24397.60      0.0
           12:36:00  24391.95      0.0
           12:37:00  24401.35      0.0
           12:38:00  0.0           24408.50
           12:39:00  24412.35      0.0
           12:40:00  24418.60      0.0
           12:41:00  24426.00      0.0
           12:42:00  24425.00      0.0
           12:43:00  24419.80      0.0
           13:36:00  24390.35      0.0
           13:43:00  0.0           24394.60
           13:44:00  0.0           24397.90
           13:45:00  0.0           24395.85
```

I am trying to:

If `Buy > 0`, discard all values after it where `Buy > 0 & Sell == 0`, if `Sell>0` then get that `Sell` Value to where the first `Buy` was.

And start discarding the next value where `Sell>0` and find the next `Buy > 0`..so on.

If the `Date`'s level has no more observation then take the last observation as the Buy/Sell dependent on the last observation

Expected output:

```
                      Buy     Sell      CloseTime  CloseDate
Date       Time                       
2018-01-03 11:36:00  24380.50     24408.50   12:38:00  2018-01-03
           12:38:00  24395.85     24412.35  12:39:00  2018-01-03 
           12:39:00  24395.85     24394.60  13:43:00  2018-01-03
           13:43:00  24394.60     24395.85  13:45:00 2018-01-03 # Last obs.
```

Things I have tried till now:

```
df[(df['Buy'] > 0) & (df['Buy'].shift(-1)>0),'Sell'] = 1
```

And then drop by checking if 1 exists.

It doesn't help me much as even the first row gets a 1.

I also tried a for loop but that is not much help while I can see a way to do it there but it will be very wasteful.

Comment: You must use `pandas.DataFrame.drop` with passed `labels` param, this `label` param in You case shoul be valid Bolean Array built with selections https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_selecting_rows_on_conditions/

Comment: @Take_Care_ I have given it a try but the conditions require a next object check which I can't figure out how to do.

Comment: So just show us more of the code, I cannot guess just from abstract example what can be wrong there.

Comment: Maybe remove multi-index from the headline since it doesn't seem relevant to the question, unless you have a solution with a non-hierarchical index (if so please add it!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is a bit different - add a new col and `drop_duplicates`:

```
df['buyorsell'] = np.where(df['Buy']>0, 'B', 'S')
df.drop_duplicates(subset='buyorsell', keep='first').iloc[:,:-1]

Time            Buy     Sell
11:36:00    24380.5     0.0
13:43:00    0.0     24394.6
```

(I left out the multi-index but it should be the same.)

That will only give you the first change, though. To get each change, swap the second line for:

```
df.loc[df['buyorsell']shift(-1) != df['buyorsell']].iloc[:,:-1]
```

And to recreate the `CloseTime`, `CloseDate` of the desired output, you can simply use `.reset_index().set_index(['Date', 'Time'], drop=False)`, to have the Date and Time both as index and as separate columns.

After a discussion in chat, it emerged that we needed to get the first and last record from each day, plus each change, so the final answer was:

```
df.groupby('Date', group_keys=False).apply(lambda df: pd.concat([df.iloc[[0, -1]], df[df.buyorsell.shift().ne(df.buyorsell)]]).drop_duplicates().sort_index())
```

To keep the last entry from each day on which no change is seen, you could instead put this in a function and use `apply`:

```
def find_day(df):
    if df.buyorsell.nunique() == 1:
        return df.drop_duplicates(subset=['buyorsell'], keep='last')
    return df[df.buyorsell.shift() != df.buyorsell].iloc[:,:-1]

df.groupby('date').apply(find_day)
```

Comment: Thanks Josh but I believe this solution will drop all duplicates i.e. if there was another Buy after the Sell signal that would be dropped as well which would not close out the trade but leave it open.

Comment: Is it correct to assume that whenever one of the columns is 0, the other is not? Are there any where both have values, or both are 0? Outside of that, this will catch the first value every time it changes from buy to sell or vice-versa

Comment: Correct assumption if one column is zero the other has a value. However I just ran the code again. It does catch the change in df once, but after that none of the others are caught. i.e. first change from buy to sell is caught but after that it doesn't catch the change back to buy/sell.

Comment: I have made some changes to the question to show what I mean.

Comment: Sorry, you're correct! I'm adding a solution to fix that

Comment: Hi Josh, sorry for replying late. Thanks for the changed solution it works on most cases except when there is no change in 'B' or 'S' state through out the day. It should catch the first 'B' or 'S' and keep the last 'B' or 'S' if there is no change. i.e. the last observation if 'B' or 'S' remains same.

Comment: OK, have added a bit at the end to deal with that. Let me know if it works!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186709/discussion-between-sid-and-josh-friedlander).